# Maximum number of teams among $n$ teams who won exactly $k$ matches

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose $n$ teams play each other (assume no tie), so there will be $\displaystyle \binom{n}{2}$ matches. Now let $k < n$. How to find maximum number of teams who won exactly $k$ matches?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  if there are $m$ teams that each win $k$ matches, they play a tournament among themselves, scoring a total of ??? points.  They then can each score $n-m$ points against the rest if they win all those games.  Compare the number of points $m$ teams can score with the number required, which is $mk$.  Find the greatest $m$ for which you can satisfy the requirement.  This works if $k \lt \frac n2$.  Otherwise invert the problem and consider how many teams can lose the required number of matches.